# "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" - trying to get children of a classname

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all children of a classname (.select-options), and apply an `onclick` attribute. When I run the javascript, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Here's my javascript:

```
function loadQuickAction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-options").childNodes;
        for(i=0; x<x.length; i++) {
            x[i].setAttribute("onclick", "subQuickAction();");
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an `HTMLCollection`, which doesn't have a `childNodes` property. The elements of the `HTMLCollection` have a `childNodes` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the returned collection from `getElementsByClassName`. Also, adding a click handler is preferrably done by assigning to the `onclick` property rather than the attribute.

```
function loadQuickAction() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var options = document.getElementsByClassName("select-options");
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var children = options[i].childNodes;
            for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
                children[j].onclick = subQuickAction;
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! It worked :) I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer once the 5 mins has passed :)